# How to recover the mro of a class given its bases?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, metaclass, method-resolution-order

Suppose we are implementing a metaclass that needs to know the *method resolution order* before the class is instantiated.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        mro = ...
```

Is there a builtin way to compute the *mro*, that is a way other than reimplementing the [C3 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization)?

Comment: `type(name, bases, namespace).__mro__[1:]` (namespace?), but there’s probably a better way, maybe.

Comment: @Ry- Well that actually seems appropriate. Maybe even simpler: pass an empty namespace to avoid generating the full class?

Comment: This is a good question.

Comment: So, isn't the MRO dynamic? Does the metaclass only need to know it at the point of class instantiation?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The mro is static and depends only on the base. That is why it can be stored in the `__mro__` attribute of an instantiated class. So the solution given by Ry does work. Of course, it also instantiate a class, adding a lot of overhead. Since this is a one time operation, it is good enough, but there might be a cleaner way.

Comment: @Ry- Please post this as an answer. This is the best answer so far and worked for my usecase. I simply replaced namespace by an empty dict to reduce the overhead of creating a class.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon yes, you are correct. I was thinking about the results of a `super` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler thing is to just create a temporary class, extract its `__mro__`, compute your things, and then create the metaclass for real:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace):
        tmp_cls = super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace)
        mro = tmp_cls.__mro__
        del tmp_cls  # Not actually needed, just to show you are done with it.
        ...
        # do stuff
        ...
        new_class = super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace)
        ...
        return new_class
```

Supposing that can't be done, due to crazy side-effects on the metaclasses of some of the super-classes on the hierarchy - then the same idea, but cloning the classes in the bases to "stub" classes before doing it - but possibly, reimplementing the C3 algorithm is easier than that - and certainly more efficient, since for each class you'd create an N ** 2 number of stub superclasses, where N is the depth of your class hierarchy (well that could be cached should you pick this route).

Anyway, the code for that could be something along:

```
stub_cache = {object: object}

def get_stub_class(cls):
    # yields an mro-equivalent with no metaclass side-effects.
    if cls is object:
        return object
    stub_bases = []
    for base in cls.__bases__:
        stub_bases.append(get_stub_class(base))
    if cls not in stub_cache:
        stub_cache[cls] = type(cls.__name__, tuple(stub_bases), {})
    return stub_cache[cls]

def get_future_mro(name, bases):
    stub_bases = tuple(get_stub_class(base) for base in bases)
    stub_cls = type(name, stub_bases, {})
    reversed_cache = {value:key for key, value in stub_cache.items()}
    return [reversed_cache[mro_base] for mro_base in  stub_cls.__mro__[1:]]

class Meta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace):
        mro = get_future_mro(name, bases)
        print(mro)
        return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace)
```

(This thing works for basic cases I've tried in interactive mode - but there might be complicated edge cases not covered, with multiple metaclasses and such)

Comment: The first case is entirely sufficient. I actually ended up simply doing `type(name, bases, {}).__mro__[1:]`